# Exchange text between web/desktop and devices

Tags: chat, clipboard

Often I have some text on a desktop that I want to put in an SMS for example. Which software can help me to easily do this exchange?

Devices are iPhone, but also Android.

Exchange by Internet is more important than local. I imagine the desktop/web side could be done by browser plugins or a website.
Ideally direct connection to clipboard/clipboard manager.

Messaging (chat) applications can do this to some extent.

Comment: As for Android, see my list of [inter-device clipboards](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/office_clipboard#group_43). Some of those might also be available for iOS.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [**PushBullet**](https://www.pushbullet.com/). You can share text, files, images and other data very easily between devices.

PushBullet has apps for both Android and iPhone. There is a Chrome plugin if you use Chrome.

Sharing data between devices is simply a matter of creating an account and then logging in from each of your devices.

You can directly send messages from your PC. Also you can see all phone notifications on your PC.

Comment: Looks good.  Any personal experience reg stability/quality?

Comment: Oh I use it everyday. It hasn't crashed till now. The transfer is very fast. It is very useful.